# Am I using Singleton approach correctly? (iOS game dev't)

Tags: objective-c

I just got into using singletons and I just want to evaluate if I'm using it correctly. I've read that singletons are evil. I've only started with game dev't so things like unit testing and multithreading doesn't reach me yet.

I separated the logic of my game into different modules. Each module has a singleton and non-singleton classes (eg. data model). I'm using the singleton as a mediator so it can interact with other modules. This allows me to work with other people since it's in manageable pieces and I only need to expose the helper methods of my singleton. He doesn't need to know how I implemented it.

Am I doing the right thing?

Examples:

- In a traditional japanese SRPG game (like FFTactics), the cells/grid for the tilemap has its own module. The character interacts with the singleton of this module.
- All my sprites are generated by an AssetManager (a singleton) which autoscales the sprite depending on the resolution-availability and resolution of the device. This is done just by a calling a method in the singleton.

Comment: isn't it better to post such question directly to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know there was a specific section for that. I've been in touch with StackOverflow while I was learning Objective-C. Just started with Game Dev't. Since some has already provided answers, I'll save that idea for my future questions. THanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely don't agree that singletons are evil. They are sometimes overused perhaps but on some occasions are just perfect for the job. In some applications it makes sense to have some kind of general data manager. The singleton pattern is used extensively in the SDK itself (app delegates, shared managers, default centers and so on). Most often these are not "pure" singletons, as in you can access a shared instance but can also create new instances if necessary.

The question you need to ask yourself is whether it would be useful to have access to a single instance of a data manager from anywhere at anytime, if it isn't then a singleton is probably not needed. If you are going to be using singletons in multi-threaded environments however, you do need to worry about race conditions (can one thread modify a resource while another is accessing it), the documentation has good explanations on how best to achieve this in Cocoa.

Comment: I also think that they aren't evil. I don't use it as a container for global variables...but to make my module global to the application. For unit testing, will it work if I expose a property that will accept an instance of another module (from the singleton)? Even though I can't find a use for it now since I can test my own module without relying to other module (using dummy data). But of course there are instances that one module heavily depends on the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do that with an instance too.

Let's say you have a `GameMap` class and a `Tile` class.  The `GameMap` represents a 2 dimension grid of `Tile` objects. (This is your FFTactics example).

```
GameMap *gameMap = [[GameMap alloc] init];
NSArray *theTiles = gameMap.tiles;
```

The instance of the `GameMap` owns the grid of tiles, and creates the tiles when the game map is created.  No singleton needed.

You may say "but I only have one `GameMap` at a time, what's the big deal?".  What about loading saved games, or loading new levels?  Well that becomes as easy as:

```
// In whatever class object owns the game map
self.gameMap = [[GameMap alloc] initWithSaveData:saveData];
```

In conclusion, create an instance of a class that has code to manage other instances of things.  Keep as little global as possible and your code will be more scalable and maintainable.

Comment: I consider entities like GameMap as non-singletons. My design approach is having a GameMapManager (a singleton) that can easily swap the map when needed, load and unload the map, etc. Of course the GameMap will still contain Tiles and my example of having the tile separated is useless in this context. The singleton instantiates its own set of objects...changing the data can be easily achieved if needed. So basically, it's just a controller (an abstract entity) not the actual data. What do you think of this approach?